# Formatting date string to desired date in Java

Tags: java

I desire to format date string ex.Jul1,201512: 00: 00AM to date in format 'dd/MM/yyyy'.
If any one knows is please share the solution with me

Comment: You need to parse date. And then format it. In which step you having troubles? And show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse your original string and then another one to format it into the desired format.